# How did Happy get holes in her clothes?

Tags: plot-explanation, scorpion

In the Scorpion episode "True Colors" as Happy and Toby leave the wine celler, Happy's clothes are fine, but in the next scene as they approach the van, Happy's clothes are swiss cheese.  What happened?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're not holes, they're white icing stains (this is much more visible in the beginning of the episode; see picture below). The stains are hastily explained by Happy as they rush to the van:

> We got out through the kitchen, I ran into a giant cake. I don't want to talk about it.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, I couldn't make out what she said, even after rewinding it a few times.